# go darwin/arm64 SDK in the MacOS

Tags: go, goland

I installed the Goland for the Apple silicon and go SDK in the macOS M1 machine. In the terminal I get -

```
$ go version
go version go1.18.3 darwin/amd64
```

When I try to debug the go application, I get the following error -

```
Debugging programs compiled with go version go1.18.3 darwin/amd64 are not supported. Use go SDK for darwin/arm64.
```

How do I install the go darwin/arm64 SDK in the MacOS?

Comment: What is the output of _Help | Find Action | About_ in GoLand?

Comment: @s0xzwasd Hi, the issue is solved and I write an answer as a solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because you downloaded the wrong file because there is a difference between amd64 and arm64, try downloading the arm64 version in the stable version.

ps : please try to uninstall the amd64 version before installing the arm64 version

[image: Download ARM64]

Answer (score 6):

I installed the correct version from the page -

https://go.dev/dl/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, not because I had the wrong Go SDK, but because I had the wrong build of GoLand. It's not a universal app, and (at least as of today) the download page will automatically try to supply the wrong one. I had to find https://www.jetbrains.com/go/download/#section=mac, and click on the little down arrow next to ".dmg" in order to choose the Apple Silicon build instead of the Intel one.

But, credit where it's due: the Apple Silicon build is great. It's far snappier.